# Enforce CRUD for Database.delete

Tags: crud

```
if (!(EMPYRAMDM__UploadedContact_Csv_Dup__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable())) {
    system.debug('**Cannot Delete the Uploaded Contact CSV Duplicates');
} else {
    Database.delete (scope, false);
}
```

I am trying delete the records using `database.delete`. I had written the above CRUD check.

In Checkmarx scan, I got this issue:

> This query looks for Delete operations that are performed without checking for isDeletable(). This may be a false positive if your code accesses only objects whose security is managed by your app and not the admin (for example OAuth states). It may also be a false positive if checks are performed outside of the dataflow in. References: CRUD Delete result path 1: Similarity Id: -1634949953 Object: scope in file: /classes/MDMDeleteCsvDupBatch.cls L 24: Database.delete (scope, false);

Comment: FLS = ***Field*** Level Security. FLS != CRUD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is false positive. The scanner rule is not getting it. However, you should change the logic to:-

```
if((EMPYRAMDM__UploadedContact_Csv_Dup__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable())) 
{
       Database.delete (scope, false);            
}
else
{ 
     // Some error message or info
}
```

If this is an Appexchange application for security review, submit a document to security team explaining the issue is not genuine and has zero harm.